# List of Arrays not working in C#

Tags: c#

```
double[] lhand = new double[3] { 0, 0, 0 };

List<double[]> LADC = new List<double[]>(); 

LADC.Add(lhand);
```

I cant understand why this code above isn't working. I followed instructions given by questions here in StackOverflow but i ve got the following errors:

> 1. Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> 2. Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> 3. 'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics.MainWindow.LADC' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
> 4. 'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.SkeletonBasics.MainWindow.lhand' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Are you sure your errors have to do with these lines of code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. The errors are from elsewhere. Correction: p.s.w.g. nailed it. If I paste your code outside of a function those are exactly the errors I get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to call `Add` outside of a method. Try to place this in a constructor or method:

```
public class MyClass {
    double[] lhand = new double[3] { 0, 0, 0 };
    List<double[]> LADC = new List<double[]>(); 

    public MyClass() {
        LADC.Add(lhand);
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not inside of a method, now it works. Thanks.